# STL in C++: no match for 'operator*'

Tags: c++, stl, reference

In this function:

```
int marshall_subscription (string sub, uint32_t sub_id, vector<u_int8_t> const & ser)
{
     //Do something here to build serial_data
      *ser = serial_data;
}
```

I get the error:

```
error: no match for 'operator*' in '*ser'
```

Is that not how you pass STL by reference?

Comment: You only need to dereference pointers, not references.

Comment: Note that for a pointer, `*p` and `p[0]` are the same.  But for a `std::vector`, `v[0]` works while `*v` does not (the closest working equivalent to `*v` is `*(v.begin())`)

Comment: @Aurelius: Unless you have a reference to a pointer.  Or an array.  And a vector is a lot like an array.

Comment: What data type is `serial_data`?

Comment: I am not sure how big your vector is or what you use it for, but if all its values are being set in this function consider returning it as the return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ser` is not a pointer, it is a value passed by reference. Hence, you do not need to dereference it.  Try:

```
ser = serial_data;
```

Comment: Which doesn't compile either.  Oh, in `const`istent moon, why do you vex me so?

Answer (score 2):

```
 *ser = serial_data;
```

`ser` is not a pointer, it is a reference so there is no need to dereference:

```
 ser = serial_data;
```

Moreover, `ser` was declared as a `const` reference, so assigning to it will cause an error. To fix, please change it to a non-`const` reference:

> ```
> int marshall_subscription(..., std::vector<u_int8_t>& ser);
> ```